# Filter multiple views with different dates on one parameter issue

Tags: tableau-api

I have two metrics: `rep_id`, `user_id`
I have three dimensions: `rep_onboard_date`, `user_application_date`, `user_enrollment_date`

I created a parameter called "Launch Date", which is a date that equals 1/1/2018. Note that I have data going back a few years before that.

I have three views:

1) columns = `month(rep_onboard_date)`, rows=`cntd(rep_id)`

2) columns = `month(user_application_date)`, rows=`cntd(user_id)`

3) columns = `month(user_enrollment_date)`, rows=`cntd(user_id)`

I would like to create a single filter on the dashboard- to filter all, pre "Launch Date" and post "Launch Date".

I tried creating three calculated fields according to http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/creating-a-filter-for-start-and-end-dates-parameters so I created:

Onboard_Date = [rep_onboard_date]>=[Launch Date]

Application_Date = [user_application_date]>=[Launch Date]

Enrollment_Date = [user_enrollment_date]>=[Launch Date]

But then I can only add one or the other (or both) as filter- which isn't what I am looking for.

Note that adding these into one filter with an "or" statement doesn't work because when setting filter=True I still get data before the Launch Date.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: why are you adding those in filters instead use those conditions in IF statemetns

Comment: @Siva I am not sure I understand, do you mind expanding?

Comment: can you share workbook?

Comment: @Siva I wish I could... but I am good with a theoretical answer- if I somewhat understand the approach I will be able to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is add one filter and add these filter conditions as if statements in calculated fields, This will be like processing inside tableau after fetching data from database instead of working directly on database.

Incase if you want to apply as filters then take 3 sheets and apply filters individually and combine sheets in dashboard.

Edit-----------------------------------------------------------------

create 3 calcualted fields:

1st calculated field:

```
if [rep_onboard_date]>=[parameter.Launch Date]
then table.field
```

2nd Calculated filed

```
if [user_application_date]>=[parameter.Launch Date]
then table.field
```

3rd Calculated Field

```
if [user_enrollment_date]>=[parameter.Launch Date]
then table.field
```

one condition is launch date should be parameter then create one more calculated field with parameter using lauch date an select true by placing on filter:

```
table.launch date> parameter.launch date
```

Comment: can you please show an example of first option? Second option I already have, but it requires 3 separate filters